# Looping through a subset of an Oracle Collection

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql

I would like some help with a bit of recursive code I need to traverse a graph stored as a collection in PL/SQL.

```
---------
|LHS|RHS|
---------
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
---------
```

Assuming 1 is the start node, I would like to be able to find 2-3 and 2-4 without looping through the entire collection to check each LHS. I know one solution is to use a global temporary table instead of a collection, but I would really like to avoid reading and writing to and from disk if at all possible.

Edit: The expected output for the above example would be an XML like this:

```
<1> 
   <2> 
      <3> 
         <5> 
         </5> 
      </3> 
      <4> 
      </4> 
   </2> 
</1>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can u post sample expected output?

Comment: How is the collection being filled? Offhand I can only think of a 2-tiered collection layout ( ie. a collection indexed by the LHS whose values are collections indexed by the RHS ), That might only make sense if you build the collections from scratch in plsql or partition the db tables where the linkage information resides, bulk-loading the data for each LHS independently. Possibly you can construct a single numerical index   like `10^n * LHS + RHS` if you know that your node ids are less than `10^n`, ...

Comment: ...  bulk-loading the linkage information and a mapping between the composite index numbers and their rank (= list of <number of nodes> consecutive integers ) into 2 collections. It will be very hard to come up with a more specific solution to fit your needs unless you provide more details ( code, table schema ).

Comment: @Tarun

The output will be ultimately be an XML like this:
     <1>
        <2>
           <3>
              <5>
              </5>
           </3>
              <4>
              </4>
        </2>
     </1>

Comment: @collapsar It will be populated using a hierarchical query. It needs to be dynamic and I don't think creating a nested collections structure will be any more efficient than just looping through on each iteration. There isn't really much more I can provide that's relevant to the question; I have a query that returns a list graph edges, and I'm doing a depth-first traversal to build some XML. I guess it's just unfortunate that Oracle doesn't allow us to do straightforward selects on table types.

Comment: @Saieden you could update your question to provide the formatted output that you're expecting to see.